# Make an arbitrary function safe to run?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, sanitization

I'm writing the docs of my program [online, in a wiki](http://gimmeplayer.org/wiki/Song_properties), and my intent is to rip that content from the program itself, either from time to time or on demand.

For extra leetness, it would be cool to the get the display functions themselves online, but this I cannot do unless I'm assured that they are safe to run, ie, they won't modify important variables, make system calls, nor steal information from the user. Is this implemented on Elisp or implementable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to be able to run your elisp code in a sandbox.  A bit of googling lead me to [sandbox.el](http://www.panix.com/~tehom/my-code/sandbox.el).  I haven't tried it, but it might be a good place to start.